# Error in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

I am not expert in Excel and it's formula. I can implement basic formulas to filter data in excelsheet but not able to work on complex things.

I am working on existing web application developed on PHP and this application uses the PHPExcel for generating excel sheet.

Now, I have a task to make changes in existing excel report and code of this report is too complex to generate excel sheet. But I have done this and trying to create excel report. While generating excel report, system is giving me below error:

```
Exception in Cell.php line 293:
November 2017 Report!G2 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured
```

After go through this error, I have found that, the formula in cell G2 is causing the error. Formula is given below:

```
=INDEX('Research Methods'!1:1048576,MATCH(B2,'Research Methods'!K:K,0),MATCH("CW",'Research Methods'!A3:BZ3,0))
```

As I already said, I am not able to get  the exact working of this formula. As well as what this above formula is doing. And without knowing the working of above formula, I am not able to rectify error.

Can anyone please, who is expert in this kind of thing, tell me the what is the error in above formula?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Assuming that your two MATCH statements actually return numbers, try it as `=INDEX('Research Methods'!A:BZ, ...`

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is giving me error, Invalid cell coordinate A.

Comment: The formula looks fine so it's probably the data causing the error.  Does the value in cell `B2` on the `Report` sheet appear anywhere in column `K` on the `Research Methods` sheet and do the letters `CW` appear on row 3 between columns B and BZ (`A3:BZ3`)? If either of these values are missing the formula will return an `N/A#` error.

Comment: If the error isn't `#N/A` or both values do exist then the formula is probably referencing a cell that contains an error.  The value that is returned should be on the junction between the column that `CW` appears in and the row that the value appears in in column `K`.

Comment: PHPExcel does not support column (`K:K`) or row ranges (`1:1048576`) in formulae.... you need to specify cell ranges instead (`K1:K1048576` or `A1:A1048576`)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be at in the first argument of the INDEX function. Your range of cells isn't properly defined.

```
=INDEX('Research Methods'!1:1048576,...
```

This specifies the rows which apply but doesn't specify the column in which to look. If your data is in column A then simply correcting your formula as follows should solve your problem:

```
=INDEX('Research Methods'!A1:A1048576,...
```

Also keep in mind that if you want the range of cells to stay constant should you drag the formula down, you should include dollar signs as follows:

```
=INDEX('Research Methods'!$A$1:$A$1048576,...
```

Comment: Should add that it's properly defined within Excel - the formula on its own will work and references all cells on the sheet.  From the comment by @MarkBaker it doesn't seem to be properly defined for `PHPExcel`.  The INDEX is looking at different rows and columns so I expect the proper reference should be `'Research Methods'!A1:XFD1048576` (I've never used `PHPExcel` so not sure).